# How to hide the 'dn:' value in Ldap unix shell commands?

Tags: ldap, unix-shell

I got a problem to solve.
How do i hide the 'dn:' part ?

dn: uid=trebbouh,ou=2017_paris,ou=2017,ou=paris,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr

This is the command I used :
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=$USER -W

Comment: Hide from whom? What is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332100/make-ldap-search-dont-show-dn ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which attributes you want to have displayed as the results of a query at the end of your query. For instance if you just want the "mail" and "uid" attributes your command would be

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=$USER -W mail uid
```

Alternatively you could just pipe the results through "grep -v dn:"

Comment: That's not what I meant :p

Comment: I just wanna hide the "dn:" part, and it seems like I just can't find a solution huh..

Comment: Write a small wrapper for the ldapsearch command that would use your text manipulator or choice, say, "cut", to alter stdout? Use an alias even?

alias ldsuid="ldapsearch ...uid=$USER | cut -d2 -f:"